# how to rearrange scatter x-axis plot using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, classification, scatter-plot, x-axis

How to change the x-axis to order 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7MoM.jpg)

here, I attached my current display of scatter plot.

Comment: Your post doesn't contain code (at least not as text), nor test data.

Comment: You could try `df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'])` to fix an order. For regular seaborn functions, also the `order=` keyword could be used.

Comment: i've tried it, and doesn't work df['Day Name'] = pd.Categorical(df['Day Name'], ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'])

Comment: Well, you didn't provide enough code.  You need the exact column name for the day as you use in your code.

Comment: it's same ..i've changed it to my column name

Comment: You still didn't [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70790731/edit) your post to add a reproducible example.    Did you call `df['...'] = pd.Categorical(df['...'], ['Monday', ...])` before you called the plot functions?